# Why does the borrow checker let me make two mutable borrows?

Tags: rust

Here is a minimal example for some behavior I stumbled on:

```
pub struct PrimeEngine {
    primes: Vec<uint>,
}

pub struct PrimeIterator<'a> {
    engine: &'a mut PrimeEngine,
    index: uint
}

impl PrimeEngine {
    pub fn new() -> PrimeEngine {
        PrimeEngine { primes: vec![] }
    }

    // Needs a &mut so it can call more_primes if needed
    pub fn is_prime(&mut self, x: uint) -> bool {
        true
    }

    pub fn iter<'a>(&'a mut self) -> PrimeIterator<'a> { // '
        PrimeIterator { engine: self, index: 0 }
    }

    fn more_primes(&mut self) {
        // Adds more primes to self.primes
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator<uint> for PrimeIterator<'a> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<uint> {
        if self.engine.primes.len() <= self.index {
            self.engine.more_primes();
        }
        let i = self.index;
        self.index += 1;
        Some(self.engine.primes[i])
    }
}
```

The following code doesn't compile, because it tries to make two mutable borrows of `engine`, once when creating the closure, and again when creating the iterator:

```
#[test]
fn test1() {
    let mut engine = PrimeEngine::new();
    engine.iter().take(5).inspect(|x| {
        assert!(engine.is_prime(*x))
    });
}
```

This code however, does compile:

```
#[test]
fn test2() {
    let mut engine = PrimeEngine::new();
    for x in engine.iter().take(5) {
        assert!(engine.is_prime(x))
    }
}
```

And I have no idea why. It needs to make a mutable borrow of `engine` to create the `Iterator`, which should prevent it from making the mutable borrow needed to invoke `is_prime`. Is this allowed for some reason? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looks like a bug, I managed to reproduce this issue with simpler code :

```
fn main() {
    let mut vector = vec!(1u, 2u);
    for &x in vector.iter() {
        let cap = vector.capacity();
        println!("Capacity was: {}", cap);
        vector.grow(cap, &0u); // be sure to cause reallocation
        *vector.get_mut(1u) = 5u;
        println!("Value: {}", x);
    }
}
```

It outputs :

```
Capacity was: 4
Value: 1
Capacity was: 8
Value: 2
```

I'm modifying the vector content and reallocating, causing the underlying slice to refer to unallocated memory (`vector.iter()` is in fact `vector.as_slice().iter()`).

It looks like a recent change, it doesn't compile on rust 0.11 due to double borrow.

I opened an issue here : https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16820

**Edit (10 sept 2014) :** The bug is now corrected : https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/17101